# Yesod.Auth.Account not actually emailing

Tags: email, haskell, authentication, yesod

I'm trying to write a Yesod-base application and frankly am somewhat out of my depth.  The current blocker is setting up new accounts via email authentication.

I've got it to the stage where the Yesod-provided page comes up requiring username, email, password and repeated-password.  I fill-in the details and click [Register].  The page now shows *A confirmation email has been sent to you@yours.com*.  However, the email doesn't arrive.  I pretty well just copied the example from [Yesod.Auth.Account](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-auth-1.4.4/docs/Yesod-Auth-Email.html).

On that machine (CentOS 7), I *can* use the *mailx* command to send myself an email so I reckon postfix is configured correctly.  So what does Yesod.Auth need, actually to be able to send the email ?

[Here is my source](http://pastebin.com/RfUd2Utb) but **I would appreciate it if this question was not polluted with comments on style etc**. as it is very much a work in progress and a learning exercise for me.  If you absolutely cannot help yourself (and there are those on stackoverflow who cannot) then please wait until the question has actually been answered.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that one must override some of the default behaviour of the **AccountSendEmail** instance.  The default behaviour is just to log a message.